# How to determine which include header file a function comes from?

Tags: c++

When learning new functions, I like to include the full name when calling them (e.g., `std::cin` instead of `cin`). Is there a similar way to include the header that the function came from? E.g., is there a way to specify the sort function is from the `<algorithm>` header, and not the `<iomanip>` header, or whatever?

For instance, it would be cool if I could call `sort` using something like `std::algorithm::sort` instead of `std::sort`. There are so many headers built in to the standard library that just using `std::*` is not actually that informative, and tells me very little specifically about where `*` is coming from.

Obviously as I get better with C++ this might not be necessary, but my goal is to learn which functions go with which headers to better learn the standard library.

If there is no such way to specify the function, is there a function I can use to determine which header supplied the function?

Ultimately I think it will be good coding practice to list the functions you will be using that are associated with each header:

```
#include <iostream>  //std::cout, std::cin
```

That way people can figure out what comes from where! Why is this not done more, given c++ community's admirable obsession with clarity about names?

Note: This question is only possible because C++ is a very non-Pythonic language. "Explicit is better than implicit" after all. :)

Comment: No, that wouldn't be a helpful feature at all. Namespaces already serve the purpose of... well, providing name spaces. Files and/or headers are generally just an implementation detail which can change (although not for the standard library).

Comment: Kerrek: my point is that the standard namespace is so vast, and there are so many possible header files, that simply using std::* is not particularly informative when it comes to code readability. I have seen code with 30 header files, many from the standard library, and no idea what comes from where. I know that std::* is not there for readability, but so that names do not clash, but why _not_ turn it up to 11 and make it completely transparent where your names are coming from?

Comment: @neuronet don't start with code that has 30 header. It can be overwhelming, and it doesn't have to be like that. Start with the basics, with simple code and work your way up.

Comment: Why is it important to know which header it came from? The important thing is "it came from the standard library" and *std::* is good for that. Anyway, as you get used to the library, this problem will go away.

Comment: This is exactly what you can do in Java , But not in c++ :)
But , I think you have to search for an IDE which may help you knowing every function where it come from ,

Comment: Mostafa that is interesting...I think that if such functionality were part of c++ from the start, folks here would likely be strident about why it was a bad idea to not use it (using similar arguments they use for not just throwing 'using namespace std' in every program). Just sayin'. :) This lack of transparency seems to go against the spirit of c++ (as I am coming to appreciate it more anyway). There is little doubt it would help clarify matters,improve readability to not need to right click and search for a function (especially the kind of code I see at work with tons of header files)

Comment: Guilerme asked _Why is it important to know which header it came from?_ I would find it useful for debugging, for readability of code, transparency of code, future-proofing (people in the future won't necessarily know what is coming from where, and you are assuming they will)). I guess I would ask what reason would someone have for thinking it is *not* important or useful?   At any rate, I think it is clear from the answers, that this functionality is not native to c++ so I'd have to do it myself as suggested by bolov below.

Comment: It might be worth noting that this would force users to write daft things like `std::iterator::iterator<std::unordered_map::unordered_map>`.

Comment: this is not the way c++ works, it's the way java works, and that's it.

Comment: Kaathe isn't that what 'using' is for? At least then it's explicit instead of something you have to go searching for on the internet. Pepper_chico, yes apparently, but what surprises me is instead of just saying 'no' people are acting nonplussed that someone would even ask. Bolov answered it, but even he/she threw in "I have never heard of someone wanting something like this" which is again a little odd (given Java). Seems I have found a blind spot perhaps? Or maybe I am just being unreasonable, and Java sucks :)

Comment: "Which header it came from" is not the right question. "Which library it came from" is. And that can be answered by the `std::` part. The fact that the `std` namespace is split through so many headers is somewhat a historic accident. You could think better of a big `#include <std>` that included everything: that would be just as informative, but slower to compile.

Comment: Many years later I am still glad I asked this question, at least to help me see why Python is so clean and nice by comparison. :) PS I am now a Python developer.

Answer (score 4):

> E.g., is there a way to specify the sort function is from the `<algorithm>` header, and not the `<iomanip>` header, or whatever?

No. C++ as a compiled language (deliberately ignoring the preprocessor) has no knowledge of your headers' filenames, and as such they have nothing to do with the names of objects and types defined in headers.

If it helps, [**there is no `std::sort` in `<iomanip>`**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip).

It's also kind of a strange thing to want to do. Overload resolution is performed by matching *argument types*, which is more than enough to disambiguate.

> For instance, it would be cool if I could call sort using something like `std::algorithm::sort` instead of `std::sort`. There are so many headers built in to the standard library that just using `std::*` is not actually that informative, and tells me very little specifically about where `*` is coming from.

It doesn't matter. You don't need to know where it's coming from. The compiler doesn't need to know where it's coming from. It's completely irrelevant to actually *using* `std::sort`.

It *is* true that the C++ standard library does not organise its contents into many sub-namespaces, instead sticking with the top-level `::std` for the most part. It could be argued that this makes coding with the standard library more of a mystery, but in fact it doesn't: it would only complicate look-up rules and make your life a lot more difficult when dealing with operator overloads, template instantiations and `friend`s.

> Ultimately I think it will be good coding practice to list the functions you will be using that are associated with each header:
>
> ```
> #include <iostream>  //std::cout, std::cin
> ```
>
> That way people can figure out what comes from where! Why is this not done more, given c++ community's admirable obsession with clarity about names?

While I do this for some POSIX/Linux sockets headers, so that I know which ones I can potentially remove in the future, I wouldn't do this for standard headers. The C++ community knows where `std::cout` is declared and if they forget then they can simply look it up.

Comment: "You don't need to know where it's coming from. The compiler doesn't need to know where it's coming from." Those two sentences are not the same. I sometimes _do_ need to know. For instance, when I am writing .h files of my own and want to include the minimal number of headers (e.g., not use 'using namespace std' in my headers). While it is clear enough that this is not do-able in c++ in any natural way, that doesn't mean it would not be useful to human users (which are distinct from compilers).

Comment: @neuronet: If you think you need to know, you are programming wrong. Let the compiler be your proxy. Fight against it, and you will fail.

Comment: So if someone needs to include the relevant header file (e.g., iostream) in a function because the compiler throws 'error: std::cin' has not been declared, it is wrong to wonder which header file they neglected to include? That is programming wrong?

Comment: @neuronet: That's a polarly opposite example. Knowing where some symbol is _not_ coming from is of course important, and for that you have the documentation (various references online, the standard, your book). This is not the same as knowing where symbols come from once you have included their header!

Comment: Of course you _can_ go to the internet to find the information needed, but my point is that it would be helpful if there were a simple way to programmatically access it, or even include the path in the function name. The two examples simply make that same point, my second one makes it more clear so you would have to agree with me. :)

Answer (score 3):

I never heard of someone wanting something like this.

One thing you could do (it's tedious, so in my opinion it's not worth it) is to create yourself the namespaces and use `using declarations` in that namespace for each name that you want.

```
#include <iostream>

namespace iostream {
    using std::cout;
    using std::endl;
}

int main() {
    iostream::cout << 24 << iostream::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

My advice would be to not do it though. Just use them by they name only, and search the net each time you are not sure where they come from. With time, you will learn them without any effort.

Comment: Thanks--so from this and the above, it is clear that I have asked about something that is not part of c++ (but apparently is possible in Java, so there are probably a couple of people before me who have wanted to do something like this). Is there a function I can call within c++ to determine the header a function came from? (Yes I know there internet exists, but I would also like to do this in my code for personal use...)

Comment: @neuronet: By bringing Java into this, you are once again conflating the concepts of _namespaces_ and _files_. The Java standard library is organised into many sub-namespaces in a way that C++'s isn't: _this_ is a valid point you could make.

Answer (score 2):

> Way to specify or determine which include header file a function comes from?

You usually do this when you are having trouble, like trying to figure out why a symbol is missing or where a header clash is occurring. Its not something you normally do at runtime as Lightness Races in Orbit and Bolov pointed out.

But if you want to do it, perform the following:

```
gcc -E t.c
```

If `t.c` is:

```
$ cat t.c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    return 0;
}
```

The output will be similar to:

```
$ gcc -E t.c
# 1 "t.c"
# 1 "<command-line>"
# 1 "t.c"
# 1 "/usr/include/stdio.h" 1 3 4
# 28 "/usr/include/stdio.h" 3 4
# 1 "/usr/include/features.h" 1 3 4
# 323 "/usr/include/features.h" 3 4
# 1 "/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/predefs.h" 1 3 4
# 324 "/usr/include/features.h" 2 3 4
# 356 "/usr/include/features.h" 3 4
...
# 866 "/usr/include/stdio.h" 3 4
extern FILE *popen (__const char *__command, __const char *__modes) ;
extern int pclose (FILE *__stream);
extern char *ctermid (char *__s) __attribute__ ((__nothrow__));
# 906 "/usr/include/stdio.h" 3 4
extern void flockfile (FILE *__stream) __attribute__ ((__nothrow__));
extern int ftrylockfile (FILE *__stream) __attribute__ ((__nothrow__)) ;
extern void funlockfile (FILE *__stream) __attribute__ ((__nothrow__));
# 936 "/usr/include/stdio.h" 3 4

# 2 "t.c" 2

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
 return 0;
}
```

Then, pipe the output through `grep` to find the function of interest.

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion. There is no simple function that will just print out which standard header file a function is from?  E.g., header_name('std::cin') that returns 'iostream'?

Comment: For finding definitions in headers, I believe [ctags](http://ctags.sourceforge.net/) is often used. I don't use it, however. I usually use an IDE (and just right click -> go to definition) and see what is opened. If I don't use an IDE, I will try a quick search. If the search fails, I will use `grep`.

Comment: Thanks for the help: I am using code::blocks and right click but do not find 'go to definition' type help, unfortunately. I will go to code::blocks forum and ask there, and come back here and report if I hear anything back.